# if statement trough for_each in terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm using terraform 0.14.2 and I have the next code:

```
resource "aws_backup_vault" "vaultrds" {
  for_each             = local.ob

  name = "vault-${each.value}"
}
```

```
locals {
    ob = toset([
     "es",
     "uk"
    ])
```

The resource iterate trough this vars and now I would like to put a conditional that if a var.anyvar exist , doesnt execute the above task like this:

```
anyvar = true

resource "aws_backup_vault" "vaultrds" {
  for_each    = var.anyvar == true : local.ob
  *(don't execute anything)*
  name = "vault-${each.value}"
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more specific? What var exists? local.ob? All variables exist, so how it can not exist? You mean, its false?

Comment: I need that if var.anyvar exist doesn't execute the task @Marcin

Answer (score 0):

First make sure if the variable isn't set, the default value is null.

```
variable "anyvar" {
    default = null
}
```

Then use a dynamic block that checks if it is not null.

```
 dynamic "aws_backup_vault" {
    for_each = var.anyvar != null ? [1] : []
    content {
      name = var.name
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html) with an `if` clause to filter elements from a collection. In this case, it seems like your goal would be served by filtering *all* elements out of `local.ob` if the variable isn't set, so that the `for_each` will either cover all of the elements or none of them:

```
resource "aws_backup_vault" "vaultrds" {
  for_each = toset([
    for s in local.ob : s
    if var.anyvar
  ])

  name = "vault-${each.value}"
}
```

The above will make `for_each` see an empty set (`toset([])`) in any situation where `var.anyvar` isn't true, which will therefore have the effect of declaring zero instances of this resource.